# use HttpClient in multiple Services .net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-4.8

I have multiple managers like `TokenManager` and `UserManager`. Both have there own interface and inherit from `Manager`.

In `TokenManager` I get the token from the identity and in `UserManager` the users. To get the users, I have to be authorized.

As of now I put the Token in a Cookie and with every request I have to get the token and set it in every call I make like in `UserManager.AllAsync(token)`.

This solution I got isn't clean and I can't get it cleaned up, so I don't have to set the token every time.

**What I have now**

`TokenManager.cs`:

```
public class TokenManager : Manager, ITokenManager
{
    public TokenManager() { }

    public async Task<IResult<TokenResponse>> GetToken(TokenRequest request)
    {
        var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(TokenEndpoints.Get, request.ToContentData());
        return await response.ToResult<TokenResponse>();
    }
}
```

`UserManager.cs`:

```
public class UserManager : Manager, IUserManager
{
    public UserManager() { }

    public async Task<IResult<List<UserResponse>>> AllAsync(string token)
    {
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
            new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token); 
            
        var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(UserEndpoints.All);

        return await response.ToResult<List<UserResponse>>();
    }
}
```

`Manager.cs`:

```
public class Manager : IManager
{
    protected readonly HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();

    public Manager()
    {
        _httpClient.BaseAddress = new System.Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MigrosProIdentity.Url"]);
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("origin", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MigrosProIdentity.origin"]);
    }
}
```

What I want to do is to set the token at login to use it when I get the users.

Something like this and then the request is authorized in all managers, but that doesn't work, because the managers doesn't use the same `HttpClient`.

```
public async Task<IResult<TokenResponse>> GetToken(TokenRequest request)
{
   var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(TokenEndpoints.Get, request.ToContentData());
   var result = await response.ToResult<TokenResponse>();
                
   _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
      new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.Data.Token);
   return result;
}
```

When I try to do this, the authoriation is null in `userManager.AllAsync()`.

What can I do to set the token at login and use it in the other services?